# Show that $\bar{x}$ can also be written as the minimizer...

Tags: calculus

I am asked to show that $\bar{x}$ can be written as

$$ \arg\min_{\alpha} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\alpha -x_i \right)^2$$

Unfortunately, I've never really gotten the hang of how to prove something like this, and now I'm stuck on this assignment. Is there a general rule you can follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe
$$(\alpha - x_i)^2 = (\alpha-\bar{x}+\bar{x}-x_i)^2=(\alpha-\bar{x})^2+2(\alpha-\bar{x})(\bar{x}-x_i)+(\bar{x}-x_i)^2\text{.}$$
This gives
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\alpha - x_i)^2 &=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\alpha-\bar{x})^2+\sum_{i=1}^{n}2(\alpha-\bar{x})(\bar{x}-x_i)+\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\bar{x}-x_i)^2 \\
&= (\alpha-\bar{x})^2\sum_{i=1}^{n}1+2(\alpha-\bar{x})\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\bar{x}-x_i)+\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\bar{x}-x_i)^2 \\
&= n(\alpha-\bar{x})^2+2(\alpha-\bar{x})\left(n\bar{x}- \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right)+\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\bar{x}-x_i)^2 \\
&= n(\alpha-\bar{x})^2+\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\bar{x}-x_i)^2
\end{align}$$
since 
$$n\bar{x}- \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i = n\left( \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}{n}\right)-\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i - \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i = 0\text{.}$$
This gives that 
$$\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\alpha - x_i)^2 = (\alpha-\bar{x})^2+\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\bar{x}-x_i)^2\text{.}$$
We can ignore $$\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\bar{x}-x_i)^2$$
since it is not dependent on $\alpha$.

Thus, it suffices to minimize $(\alpha-\bar{x})^2$ with respect to $\alpha$. Since $(\alpha-\bar{x})^2 \geq 0$ (since it is a squared term), minimizing this amounts to setting $$(\alpha-\bar{x})^2 = 0 \Longleftrightarrow \alpha = \bar{x}\text{.}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

One possible approach:

Try to differentiate $$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\alpha -x_i \right)^2$$ with respect to $\alpha$ using chain rule and equate it to zero. Solve for $\alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding, we want to minimize
$$ \frac{1}{n} \biggl[ \sum_{i=1}^n\left(\alpha^2 - 2\alpha x_i + x_i^2 \right) \biggr] = \alpha^2 - 2\alpha \bar x + \frac1n \sum_i x_i^2. $$
We could do this easily with calculus, but it is not necessary: Completing the square yields
$$ (\alpha - \bar x)^2 - \bar x^2 + \frac1n \sum_i x_i^2, $$
which clearly has a unique minimum at $\alpha = \bar x$.